# Onclick Change the Class Style Value without changing Class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change a value of a Class Style Property Color from RED to GREEN  on click.

```
<style>
.c1
{
color : RED;
}

</style>

<a id="a1" class="c1" onclick="changeclassstyle()">
Hi
</a>

<script>
function changeclassstyle()
{
/* here i need to change the style of class c1 */
}
</script>
```

I need to change the color of c1 class to GREEN.

Note: I **dont** want it to be done with **"ID"**  & I **dont** want to create **new** Class and change the class name. I want it to happen with same class name.

Comment: do you mean want to change `<style>`?

Comment: @agus-putra-dana: css style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function changeclassstyle() {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("c1");
  for (var i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
    c[i].style.color = "green";
  }
}
```

```css
.c1 {
  color : RED;
}
```

```html
<a id="a1" class="c1" onclick="changeclassstyle()">
Hi
</a>
```

Comment: its script not style.. my mistake.. changed it now

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="a1" class="c1" onclick="changeclassstyle(this);">
Hi
</a>


<script>

function changeclassstyle(obj)
{
obj.style.color='green';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery version

```js
function changeToGreen(elem) {
  $("." + elem.className).css("color", "green");
}
```

```css
.c1 {
  color: RED;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="a1" class="c1" onclick="changeToGreen(this)">
Hi
</a>
<br/>
<p class="c1">
  Test
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to add javascript to the tag itself you can do it this way:

```
var c= document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");


       for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)  {
            c[i].onclick=function(){       //on click here instead of on tag

                this.style.color="green";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:active

seudoclass :active

```
.class-label {  
    display: flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:rgb(201, 201, 201) ; 
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: monospace;  
}

.class-label:active {
    background-color: salmon;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).